# Class which supports injectable mocked object but also using statement c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How do I go about creating a class which wraps all EF repository calls in a Using statement whilst also supporting an injectable interface of the repository?

I can't seem to wrap my head around having this class support 2 different types of instantiation.

```
public class MyClass(IRepo repo)
{
    _repo = repo;
}

public void MyMethod()
{
   using ( var db = new DbContxt() )
   {
        var repo = new Repo(db);
        repo.GetById(1);
   }
}
```

In essence, the life-time of the 'db' object is the lifetime of the method call. Whereas the lifetime of 'db' would be managed outside of the class if injected.

Comment: I think your code needs a bit of a rewrite!

Comment: It's easy to tell that is just dummy code for clarification purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You could structure it this way:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IRepo _repo;

    //or if you want a parameterless constructor...
    public MyClass() : this(new Repo()) { }      

    public MyClass(IRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public MyObject MyMethod(int id)
    {
        _repo.GetById(id);
    }
}

public interface IRepo
{
    MyObject GetById(int id);
}

public class Repo : IRepo
{
    public MyObject GetById(int id)
    {
        using ( var db = new DbContext())
        {
            //do your db related stuff here
         }
    }
}
```

You would need a way of injecting an instance of `Repo` into `MyClass` so maybe take a look at IoC.

This way, you can easily mock `IRepo` for testing purposes.

Comment: Moreover, dbcontext factory should be injected in Repo too.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov was just showing one way of doing things, not a complete example

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it that way. Have a parameterless constructor for your `Repo`, and instantiate the `DbContext` there. You can also have an overload for it that takes a `DbContext`, but you don't have to go about it that way. The point is to let each layer only worry about what it needs on its own. Let the IOC container inject everything as it is created, don't make objects for a different layer inside your methods.